# Fast Method to Intersect two Integer Quadratic Beziers?

Tags: geometry, integer, bezier, curve, quadratic

Given two Quadratic Beziers in 2D with integer coordinates, what is the best way to find their intersection point(s)? Also interesting is an early rejection if they do not intersect. If it makes it easier, they can both be assumed to be monotone in both x and y.
Only intersections that are representable by subdivision to integers of the input curves are valid.

Answer (score 3):

[This document](http://cagd.cs.byu.edu/~557/text/ch7.pdf) explains various methods for finding the intersection of curves.

Comment: The link above is dead. The file can still be found at http://replay.waybackmachine.org/20090521080353/http://cagd.cs.byu.edu/~557/text/ch7.pdf, but it would be better if someone had a more permanent place to store it.

Comment: It is chapter 7 of the book, "COMPUTER AIDED GEOMETRIC DESIGN", 2012, by  Thomas W. Sederberg. Get the bok at https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1000&context=facpub#page99.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that doesn't work.
This way, you'll only find a small (usually empty) subset of the intersections between Q1 and Q2, namely those where the intersection points lay at the same curve parameter t with respect to both curves involved.